# directory structure for download without to save it on server

Tags: php

I have a project where I would like to create a dynamical directory tree structure without to save it on server, compress it and push it to download. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [`ZipArchive::addEmptyDir`](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addemptydir.php), which can be used to create empty directory in ZIP archive. You later can add files to that directory.

You'll still need to save the resulting archive to disk...

```
$file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addEmptyDir('newDirectory');
$zip->addFromString('newDirectory/demo.txt', 'file contents');
$zip->close();

// Stream the file to the client 
header('Content-Type: application/zip'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_archive_file.zip"'); 
readfile($file); 
unlink($file);
```

If you desire to stream the archive without saving the archive on your end, you may try to look at [PHPZip class](https://github.com/Grandt/PHPZip)

Comment: thanks! than I could implement a function what would delete the created file after download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `passthru` with combination of command line archiving utilities, ie:

```
passthru("tar dir0/ dir1/ dir2/dir23/dir234/ dir4/file4.txt | gzip -f");
```

Comment: Doesn't this implies that you already have those directories on server? ;)

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the question, I thought that OP wants to include only parts of directory structure without saving it to server in auxiliary file.