# Creating a GZipped tar file and dynamically streaming it via PHP?

Tags: php, zip, archive, tar, zlib

Is there an easy interface like ZipArchive for tar.gz archives that allows me to stream the archive to the client rather than save it on the server? And if so, could someone show me how?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757412/258674

Answer (score 3):

You can direct the tar command with passthru() or exec() to send the tar.gz file to stdout.  E.g.

```
tar cfz - name1 name2 ...
```