# PHP: how to tar folder and send directly to client using passthru?

Tags: php, archive, tar, passthru

I can directly download database dump using:

```
$filename = $database . '-' . date("d-m-Y_(G_i_s)") . ".sql.gz";
$mime = "application/x-gzip";


header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');


$cmd = "mysqldump --opt -h $host -u $username -p$password $database";


passthru($cmd);
exit(0);
```

Can I do it with .tar file make from directory? Just generate file and download it, without saving on server?

I can execute this (and file is correct):

```
exec('tar -czf /path/download/backup.tar.gz /path/download/');
```

But I don't want to store backup file on server... I want to download it directly.
I tried to do something like my database dump example... but without success.

Any ideas how to do it?

EDIT:

Thanks for help. Removing -f was good idea.

Now it works:

```
$filename = 'download-' . date("d-m-Y_(G_i_s)") . ".tar.gz";
$mime = "application/x-tgz";


header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
$cmd = "tar -cz " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/download/";

passthru($cmd);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Leave the `-f` filename flag out, then `tar` sends it directly to stdout, suitable for `passthru()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a GZipped tar file and dynamically streaming it via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162759/creating-a-gzipped-tar-file-and-dynamically-streaming-it-via-php)

Comment: OMG thanks :) removing -f was enough.

One more question - how can I set directory structure in tar.gz file?

Now I get full path with home/user/domains/domain.pl/public_html...

I'd like to have only files from folder included in my command.

Comment: `$cmd = "tar -cz -C " . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . " download";` the `-C` option is equivalent to changing to the specified directory beforehand.